# How to use buttons in displaying text in a textview? just like it is a keyboard

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I am new to Android programming and I want to make a simple game. I want to have a group of buttons that will use to become a keyboard just like in 4 pics 1 word, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about:

- Create smaller buttons with labels of the letters("keys") you want to be on them,
- Put them all in one relative layout where they can be arranged automatically.
- Assign an onClick Listener to each of those buttons (*I suggest using an array to manage the id's of each of the buttons, ignore if you have a better means*),
- Call an event or method that adds a text to the textfield.

> **Scenario**: Say: I press a button marked 'X', get a method that watches for the button containing 'X' and concatinate 'X' to all the
>   text that is in the textfield (if their was any). get the length of
>   the word in the text field (`int x = userAnswer.length()`) and see if
>   (`x=lengthOfCorrectAnswer`) if condition is true, compare userAnswer
>   to realAnswer.

Comment: Thanks for the idea :) I will work on it

Comment: @Antonio You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if it works out for you.

Comment: Ive done it bro, thanks for the help but how can I prevent repetition of array?

Comment: @Antonio How are you using the array?

Comment: @Antonio You can use HashSet in place of Arrays if you want only unique values/elements in the array. Here is a [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashset_add.htm) that can help with HashSet if you've never used it before

Comment: HashSet is very new to me, but after I read it, It gives me an idea thanks again bro

Comment: @Antonio You are welcome. Hashset can accept null values.. you might want to remember that at all times. Code on!